# Copying sql files from JdbcTemplate wih Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, sqlite

I try to write some datas in a sqlite3 database.
To do so, I execute :

`jdbcTemplate.execute(".read java/tmp.sql");`

Here, `tmp.sql` contains :

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

... somes inserts

COMMIT;
```

Doing so gives me this error message :

`java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ".": syntax error)`

As a consequence, would you know a way to copy a sql file using sqlite3 and Spring's jdbctemplate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JdbcTemplate execute method with one string argument needs a sql query here. 
If you need execute all file it will be better to use ResourceDatabasePopulator
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ResourceDatabasePopulator.html